# Python: Efficient way to create equal length sublists from given list with repetition allowed and order does not matter

Tags: python, algorithm

So I have a list of 151 items and need sublists of length 6 from the given list, the conditions are that repetition of items is allowed and order does not matter. Shorter example for explanation.

```
list_given = [1, 2]

possible_sublists = [
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2],
[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2],
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
[1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2],
[1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
]

Not allowed sublists would be any permutation of the above solutions, like [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2] is the same as [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1].
```

I tried a recursive approach at first but the stack gets very deep very quickly.
I have implemented an iterative solution but the for loops have to complete **151^6** = `1,18,53,91,15,88,401` iterations while the required is **156 C 6(n+r-1 C r)** = `18,16,16,99,556`  which makes `1,18,35,74,98,88,845` wasted iterations and adds more to the time complexity. How can I make it more efficient to avoid these large numbers of computations? And on top, I also have to make sure there are no repeated teams as mentioned above so O(n) time complexity adds to the current complexity where *n* changes as new sublists are added to the global_set.
**Current Algorithm**

```
from collections import Counter
def make_teams(poke):
    global_set = []
    for i in poke:
        for j in poke:
            for k in poke:
                for l in poke:
                    for m in poke:
                        for n in poke:
                            temp = Counter([i, j, k, l, m, n])
                            if temp not in global_set:
                                global_set.append(temp)
    return global_set
```

Comment: can't you sort the sublists and take the unique sublists of length 6?

Comment: creating the sublists is where the problem starts

Answer (score 1):

As you've pointed out there are 18.16bio sublists (156!/6!150!)

Good luck!

```
N=151
global_list = []
for i in range(N):                                                                                                                                                     
    for j in range(i,N):                                                                                                                                                   
        for k in range(j,N):                                                                                                                                                   
            for l in range(k,N):                                                                                                                                                   
                for m in range(l,N):                                                                                                                                                   
                    for n in range(m,N):                                                                                                                                                   
                        global_list.append([i,j,k,l,m,n])                                                                                                                       

print(global_list)
```

Comment: It produces repeated lists, for example try :- ```[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]```.

Comment: with N=2, it produces the 7 subsets above right, just with 0's and 1's instead of 1's and 2's.

Comment: Sorry I've misread it.

Comment: Ok, can you help me with the complexity of the algorithm you have(just a rough approx) and also how does it prevent repetition of sublists?

Comment: Assuming that `k=6` is fixed, then the complexity is `O(n^6)` as the number of sub-lists is `(n+k-1)!/(k!(n-1)!) = 1/720 x (n+5)(n+4)...(n+1)n`

Answer (score 1):

Use `itertools.combinations_with_replacement`:

```
list_given = [1, 2]
for combination in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(list_given, 6):
    print(combination)

->
(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2)
(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2)
(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2)
(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2)
(1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)
(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)
```

But note that when `list_given` has 151 elements, you're going to get ***a lot*** of combinations! That's why example iterates over the combinations instead of putting them all in a list: the resulting list would be huge for 151 elements.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of the possible number of combinations but I will give this module a try as well.(Hopefully, this reduces the time complexity)